# Django- admin installation error - Failed building wheel for screen

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I published my project on Windows server, but domain.com/admin is not working. As a result of research on the internet, I wanted to install Django-admin, but I am getting an error. I didn't have such a problem on my computer.

```
         Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\source\str_util.cp312-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\source\str_util.cp312-win_amd64.exp
  str_util.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE
  build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\screen\str_util.cp312-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1120
  [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for screen
Failed to build screen
ERROR: Could not build wheels for screen, which is required to install pyproject.toml- 
based projects

C:\inetpub\vhosts\domain.com.tr\httpdocs>
```

Urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('sitemap.xml', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, 
name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
] 

if settings.DEBUG:
  urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Error Detail
[image]

Comment: Try to upgrade pip using this command `pip install pip --upgrade` if it's not latest version.

Comment: Unfortunately it could not be resolved. I updated the error details, can you please check again?